# React + Node + Express app deployed on heroku shows a blank page for no match 404 routes

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku, react-router

I'v built a MERN stack app. Everything works fine locally but deployed app on heroku does not show my custom 404 page for no match routes. I had a hard time figuring out this problem.

Here is the link to my app on heroku: [my-app-on-heroku](https://ghafour-natours-react.herokuapp.com/)

If any further information is required please let me know to include it

Any help would be appreciated.


**app.js**

```
app.use('/api/v1/books', bookRouter);
app.use('/api/v1/users', userRouter);

// Catch all unknown routes ( this middleware runs after all routes have been defined !)
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  // Serve static files
  app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../client', 'build')));

  app.get('*', (req, res, next) => {
    // Serve index.html file if it doesn't recognize the route
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../client', 'public', 'index.html'));
  });
}

// Final middleware, Global Error Handler
app.use(globalErrorHandler);

module.exports = app;
```

**Routes.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Router, Route, Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

import history from '../history';
import Layout from './HOC/Layout.jsx';
import Home from './pages/Home';
import Login from './pages/Login';
import SignUp from './pages/SignUp';
import UserPanel from './pages/UserPanel/Account';
import PasswordReset from './pages/PasswordReset';
import NotFound from './pages/NotFound';

class Routes extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { currentUser } = this.props;

    return (
      <Router history={history}>
        <Layout>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact>
              <Home />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/login" exact>
              {currentUser ? <Redirect to="/" /> : <Login />}
            </Route>
            <Route path="/signup" exact>
              {currentUser ? <Redirect to="/" /> : <SignUp />}
            </Route>
            <Route path="/password-reset" exact>
              {currentUser ? <Redirect to="/" /> : <PasswordReset />}
            </Route>
            <Route path="/password-reset/:token" exact>
              {currentUser ? <Redirect to="/" /> : <PasswordReset />}
            </Route>
            <Route path="/me/settings" exact>
              {currentUser ? <UserPanel /> : <Redirect to="/login" />}
            </Route>
            <Redirect from="/me" to="/me/settings" />
            <Route path="/404" exact>
              <NotFound />
            </Route>
            <Redirect to="/404" />
          </Switch>
        </Layout>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ user: { currentUser } }) => ({ currentUser });

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Routes);
```

Comment: instead of `Redirect` just try adding something like `<Route component={NotFound} />`......You can replace last `Route` and `Redirect` with this..... read [here](https://ui.dev/react-router-v4-handling-404-pages/)

Comment: @RohitAmbre thanks for your comment. unfortunately it doesn't solve the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with serving `index.html` file in the **app.js**. It must be served from the `build` folder instead of `public`.

**app.js (modified)**

```
app.use('/api/v1/books', bookRouter);
app.use('/api/v1/users', userRouter);

// Catch all unknown routes ( this middleware runs after all routes have been defined !)
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  // Serve static files
  app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../client', 'build')));

  app.get('*', (req, res, next) => {
    // Serve index.html file if it doesn't recognize the route
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../client', 'build', 'index.html')); // <- Here !
  });
}

// Final middleware, Global Error Handler
app.use(globalErrorHandler);

module.exports = app;
```